# Analysing a circuit with an inverting amplifier

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier

As I finished my bachelor's a while ago I had some trouble analysing this circuit. I am aware of Kirchhoff's law.

Given here is that the absolute value of Av is zero,
which leads, as far as I understand, to a short circuit on Zout and Yin.

Required is Vout. As far as I understand there are two equations, first:
Vout,n = Iout * Zl
Second:
Iout(Zg+R1+R2+Zl) = Vg-Vn,1 + Vn,2

and we are supposed to substitute the second eq. in the first to solve for Vout.

However, the solution had another way of describing Vout which is:

Vout = -IR2 + Vn,2

Can some one explain this misunderstanding?

[image: inverting amp]

Comment: All resistors with a value of zero?

Comment: no it is the temperature that equals zero